# Does Hyper Threading will decrease the performance of Docker?

Tags: docker, hyperthreading

I have the below configuration server, In this we are running only Docker, All the applications are running as Docker container , Expect Docker , no other application are installed in the OS

**System Information :**

```
- Server Model            :  Dell Power Edge R440 
- Number of CPU           :  2 
- Number of Cores Per CPU :  10 Memory (RAM) - 64 GB
- Hyper Threading         : Enabled 
- Virtualization          : Enabled 
- Operating System        : CentOS 7
```

I have gone through Dell BIOS tuning guide.[(Dell Power Edge Bios tuning for performance power)](https://downloads.dell.com/solutions/general-solution-resources/White%20Papers/12g_bios_tuning_for_performance_power.pdf)
In that they are suggesting to Enable Hyper threading (Logical Processor), and their default is Hyper Threading( Logical Processor) Enabled.

**Does Hyper Threading will decrease the performance of Docker?**

Containers running in docker are
- Grafana
- PostgreSQL
- EMQX
- Prometheus
- Golang

Output of **lscpu**

```
Architecture           : x86_64
CPU op-mode(s)         : 32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order             : Little Endian
CPU(s)                 : 40
On-line CPU(s) list    : 0-39
Thread(s) per core     : 2
Core(s) per socket     : 10
Socket(s)              : 2
NUMA node(s)           : 2
Vendor ID              : GenuineIntel
CPU family             : 6
Model                  : 85
Model name             : Intel® Xeon® Silver 4210 CPU @ 2.20GHz
Stepping               : 7
CPU MHz                : 999.963
CPU max MHz            : 3200.0000
CPU min MHz            : 1000.0000
BogoMIPS               : 4400.00
Virtualization         : VT-x
L1d cache              : 32K
L1i cache              : 32K
L2 cache               : 1024K
L3 cache               : 14080K
```